# Can't start httpd service in docker image

Tags: docker, httpd

I have the following Dockerfile that should start a centos machine and install httpd:

```
FROM centos:centos6.6
RUN yum install -y httpd
RUN chkconfig httpd on; 
RUN /etc/init.d/httpd start
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I build the image:

```
docker build --no-cache -t centos_http .
```

The build says:

```
...
Step 4/6 : RUN /etc/init.d/httpd start
---> Running in 0766e84ec292
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully  qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2 for ServerName
[  OK  ]
...
Successfully built 5380a0bacdfb
```

But if I run the image:

```
docker run  -p 8090:80 -it  5380
[root@eda7400a46a9 /]# ps -ef | grep httpd | grep -v grep
[root@eda7400a46a9 /]#
```

httpd is not running!
if I execute manually /etc/init.d/httpd start, inside the image, it works fine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing completely wrong. `RUN` command will be executed only during build. You should use something like the following

```
FROM centos:6.6

RUN yum install -y httpd

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Also you can take a look at [official apache Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/17166574dea6a8c574443fc3a06bdb5a8bc97743/2.4/httpd-foreground)